# Django Celery in production

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I have everything I want to do with `django-celery` working on my development machine locally. I run Django, `djcelery`, `cellery` and the broker (Amazon SQS). It sends tasks and just works.

I can set this all up like I have done locally (i.e. all on one
machine), but what happens when I want to distribute tasks to another
machine/share tasks etc.? Is this a copy of the current machine (with Django, `djcelery` and `celery`) and all connection to the same SQS? How does this work? If they all connection to the same broker do they just 'know'? or does it not work like this?

Is it ok to start off with everything on one machine like I did in development (I will daemonize celery in production)?

Comment: You can start with "all" in one machine as long as it works for you, depending on the site you need to host, you can have a plan for scaling, but for a start having all together is a perfect fit. I have it all that way, and I use Linode so I can scale the instance if I need more resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon SQS is a Simple Queueing Service, jobs go in wait to be run and then removed from the queue once complete. Celery simply reads off of this queue.

Celery can scale both horizontally and vertically. You need celery to process more jobs faster? Give your machine more resources, up the worker count, thats vertical scaling, or boot more smaller machines which is horizontal scaling. Either way your celery workers are all consuming the same queue on SQS. It does depend on what your celery jobs are doing as to how the rest of your infrastructure will be affected. If they are writing to a DB the more workers you have the higher the load on your DB so you would need to look at scaling that too.

It is OK to start off with the "all" on one machine approach. As the demand on your app grows you can start looking at moving celery workers off to more machines or give your all in one server more resources.

Does this help? :)

Comment: I really does help thanks, it give me a starting point. One thing, I noticed was that when I booted two development machines up (same app) they both stared to consume the SQS jobs (as you described). perfect, but how does it know? I mean if I had secondary machine I may only want it to process just a set of tasks and not run my full app. Its was like magic, but I want to know, how it knows when the second server came on line, how it knew to process the same tasks? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The queue server doesn't know anything about celery or anything about your app. It's just a store where you can queue jobs. When celery boots it will check the queue for a job, if there is one it will process, once it's done it will check the Q again for another job and keep checking until there is one. This will happen x number of celery workers you have checking the queue.